# aplib decompression

Tags: assembly, compression

```
aP_depack_asm:
    ; aP_depack_asm(const void *source, void *destination)

    _ret$  equ 7*4
    _src$  equ 8*4 + 4
    _dst$  equ 8*4 + 8

    pushad

    mov    esi, [esp + _src$] ; C calling convention
    mov    edi, [esp + _dst$]

    cld
    mov    dl, 80h
    xor    ebx,ebx

literal:
    movsb
    mov    bl, 2
nexttag:
    call   getbit
    jnc    literal-------jump if no carry

    xor    ecx, ecx
    call   getbit
    jnc    codepair

    xor    eax, eax
    call   getbit
    jnc    shortmatch

    mov    bl, 2
    inc    ecx
    mov    al, 10h

.getmorebits:
    call   getbit
    adc    al, al
    jnc    .getmorebits

    jnz    domatch

    stosb
    jmp    nexttag

codepair:
    call   getgamma_no_ecx
    sub    ecx, ebx
    jnz    normalcodepair

    call   getgamma
    jmp    domatch_lastpos


shortmatch:
    lodsb
    shr    eax, 1
    jz     donedepacking

    adc    ecx, ecx
    jmp    domatch_with_2inc

normalcodepair:
    xchg   eax, ecx
    dec    eax
    shl    eax, 8
    lodsb
    call   getgamma

    cmp    eax, 32000
    jae    domatch_with_2inc
    cmp    ah, 5
    jae    domatch_with_inc

    cmp    eax, 7fh
    ja     domatch_new_lastpos

domatch_with_2inc:
    inc    ecx

domatch_with_inc:
    inc    ecx

domatch_new_lastpos:
    xchg   eax, ebp
domatch_lastpos:
    mov    eax, ebp

    mov    bl, 1

domatch:
    push   esi
    mov    esi, edi
    sub    esi, eax
    rep    movsb
    pop    esi
    jmp    nexttag

getbit:
    add    dl, dl
    jnz    .stillbitsleft
    mov    dl, [esi]
    inc    esi
    adc    dl, dl
  .stillbitsleft:
    ret

getgamma:
    xor    ecx, ecx

getgamma_no_ecx:
    inc    ecx
  .getgammaloop:
    call   getbit
    adc    ecx, ecx
    call   getbit
    jc     .getgammaloop

    ret

donedepacking:
    sub    edi, [esp + _dst$]
    mov    [esp + _ret$], edi ; return unpacked length in eax

    popad

    ret
```

Above is the aplib decompression. It has been mentioned that it is a derivation of lz78.
I want to know the meaning of `getbit`, how and where in the `algorithm` it uses for reading codes from dictionary.

Comment: I want to know where is the compressed code extracted from dictionary.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you have done? On your research? You must expand your question in order for people to help.

Comment: I am new to compression algoroithms. This is one of the compression algorithm used in lot of places. It is possibly a derivation of lz77 or lz78. My need is to write a decoder for malware using this algorithm. I went through the theories of lz77 and lz78 but I am not able to relate this algorithm to lz77 or lz78.I want to know why the functions getbit and getgamma are used. How are these functions used to create the dictionary. If anyone could help to understand the algorithm clearly it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Function getbit is responsible for reading one bit from the input data stream (which is "mixed", i.e. contains pure bytes and groups of 8 individual bits packed into bytes).

The bit-reading is done by storing 8 bits at a time in the register dl, and shifting these bits to the left (add dl,dl does it). If after shifting the register dl becomes equal to zero, this means that all bits have been shifted out and another byte needs to be read from the stream, which is done in the code:

```
getbit:
    add    dl, dl
    jnz    .stillbitsleft
    mov    dl, [esi]
    inc    esi
    adc    dl, dl
.stillbitsleft:
    ret
```

The actual algorithm used in ApLib is original, but it is built on foundations very different from LZ78 and has a lot more to do with the LZ77. Basically, at each iteration of the decompressor loop one reads one bit from the input stream and if it is 0, a byte is copied from the input stream into the output. If one the other hand this bit is 1, decompressor knows that a match would have to be copied from the already decompressed data. This idea of a signal bit is from LZSS. The details of the match are specified in the compressed data stream too. A less usual feature of the format includes the possibility of using rep-offsets, i.e. command that allows reusing offsets. This idea is likely to have been borrowed from LZX and this is the feature that makes ApLib significantly better at compressing compared to many other fixed format LZ77/LZSS compressors.